# How to get inapp update on flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, updates, in-app

I'm new to flutter developing. i'm trying to implementing the in app update but it cause error and throws exception

> Unhandled Exception: type 'PlatformException' is not a subtype of type 'String'``

How to get in app update in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [upgrader](https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader) package which displays an update dialog whenever a newer version of the app is available.

Comment: i used in_app_updater package but there is error ocuured like```Unhandle exception on messgae code```

Comment: Test in release mode, you cannot able to test [in_app_update](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update) package in  locally installed (Debug Mode)apk